# Using a string variable in expression for R for subscript/superscript

Tags: r, expression, subscript, superscript

We can use subscript or superscript in a plot title in R using the following

```
plot(1,1, main=expression('title'^2))  #superscript

plot(1,1, main=expression('title'[2])) #subscript
```

However, what if I want to use a string variable in expression. For example,

```
my_string="'title'^2"

plot(1,1, main=expression(my_string))
```

Clearly, this doesn't work and the plot title just becomes my_string rather than  title^2.

Is it possible to use a string variable inside expression?

Thanks,
Brij.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make an expression from a string, you need to parse it. Try this

```
my_string <- "'title'^2"
my_title <- parse(text=my_string)
plot(1,1, main=my_title)
```

If you just wanted to swap out certain parts of the expression with a string value, you can use something like `bquote`

```
my_string <- "title"
my_title <- bquote(.(my_string)^2)
plot(1,1, main=my_title)
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work. But it appears if I use my_string <- "'my title'^2", then the space between my and title confuses parse.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that problem. `parse(text=my_string)` with the `my_string` you provided works just fine for me. Are you sure your inner string is in quotes?

Comment: I had an additional step in my code and I figured it out. Thank you for your time and help. Much appreciated.

Comment: How to get 2 as some variable?